# Does MonoTouch support C# dynamics?

Tags: c#, dynamic, xamarin.ios, xamarin

C# Mono development for iOS has certain restrictions due to Apple's requirement to precompile the code, i.e. no JIT compilation is allowed. Because of this calls such as Reflection.Emit are not supported. But I wonder if C# dynamics can be used in C# compiled for iOS.

For example:

repository.Find(repository.UserName == "John");

Here "repository" is a dynamic object with static method "Find" and dynamic property "UserName". This approach works fine on all modern Windows-based .NET platforms, I believe it also works on Mono for Android. But what about MonoTouch? In principle there shouldn't be restrictions to dynamically resolve dynamic properties based on runtime information - unless perhaps legal constraints that Apple is so good in.

Comment: From http://tirania.org/monomac/archive/2011/Apr-06.html: *There is one important limitation: C# 4.0 dynamic support is not functional, since it requires dynamic code generation to work.*

Comment: That's a pity! But not all dynamic is about code generation, is it? Or Apple is so strict that any language syntax not resulting in precompiled binaries is prohibited?
Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: That is my understanding, yes.  Apple pre-approves all code within iOS applications; generated code doesn't exist until it is generated, so they can't control it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Last I checked, dynamic is not supported due to JIT prohibition by Apple. It is true in the Android Xamarin tools you can take advantage of the dynamic keyword, but Apple requires precompiled code. There is an excellent .NET Rocks podcast on these tools that describe an overview of working with these various platforms with these tools.